# Group dataframe on column values whilst summing over another column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe like below

```
   A     B   C   D         
0  cat   5   aa  X
1  wolf  8   bb  Y
2  dog   3   cc  Z
3  cat   6   aa  X
3  dog   6   cc  Z
```

I want to group by A and sum over C. I know I can do the following

```
>>>df.groupby('A').sum().C

A     C
cat   7 
wolf  1
dog   9
```

but it returns a series and I want all the static data for each value of A to get something like

```
   A     B   C   D         
0  cat  11   aa  X
1  wolf  1   bb  Y
2  dog   9   cc  Z
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How is your cat sum 7?

Comment: APpologies, I have updated for correct figure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) to overwrite column 'B' in original df and then call [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates):

```
In [95]:
df['B'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('sum')
df = df.drop_duplicates('A')
df

Out[95]:
      A   B   C  D
0   cat  11  aa  X
1  wolf   8  bb  Y
2   dog   9  cc  Z
```